# javascript "ors" - can they be combined into an array?

Tags: javascript

wondering if I can make my javascript more efficient.
I have a var JSP = "the jsp's name"

And I have statements in a javascript validation file:

```
if(( JSP == "test.html" ) || ( JSP == "test1.html") || ( JSP == "test2.html" )) then blah blah blah.
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: `if( JSP == "test.html" || JSP == "test1.html"|| JSP == "test2.html" )` is the shortest I can make it. EDIT: If your real urls are so similar, you could use regex to check if the filename starts with test, but I assume this was just for explaining reasons.

Comment: Also, just in case you didn't know, you don't use `then` in javascript.

Comment: @OptimusCrime - yeah, the urls are not similar at all, just written as an example.

Comment: @Alxandr - yes, no then - just writing an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that `JSP` contains a string, it's slightly more efficient to use `===` rather than `==`. Also note that you don't need all those parens:

```
if (JSP === "test.html" || JSP === "test1.html" || JSP === "test2.html") {
    // do something
}
```

You could also use a regular expression:

```
if (/^test[12]?\.html$/.test(JSP)) {
    // do something
}
```

...but it depends what you mean by "efficient." The series of `===` will be very efficient at runtime.

Separately, you *could* use a `switch`:

```
switch (JSP) {
    case "test.html":
    case "test1.html":
    case "test2.html":
        // Do it
        break;
}
```

...but I wouldn't call it more efficient.

I definitely would *not* put the options in an array, because searching through the array will not be efficient. But you can use a map:

```
var pages = {
    "test.html":  true,
    "test1.html": true,
    "test2.html": true
};
```

...and then this test:

```
if (pages[JSP] === true) {
    // do something
}
```

...which results in a fairly efficient property lookup. That's only reasonable if you create the object *once* and reuse it.

(You might have people say "Or just use `if (pages[JSP]) { ... }`. But that fails if JSP happens to contain "toString" or "valueOf" or any of several other inherited properties blank objects get from `Object.prototype`. It's fine if you're *certain* it won't have any of those values, though.)

Comment: the map method is perfect, as I have to do this with about 30 blocks of validation. So reusing the if(page[JSP] === true is perfect.

Comment: @Jason: Good deal, glad that helped!

Answer (score 2):

You could create an object with those keys:

```
var theThings = { "test.html": true, "test1.html": true, "test2.html": true };

if (theThings[JSP]) { /* whatever */ }
```

If there are only three or four, it might not be worth it, but if there are dozens it'd definitely be faster, especially if the test gets made several times.

*edit* — wow I'm crying a little inside here, guys.  Property name lookups are going to be *way* faster than linear searches through an array.

Comment: You could one-line this AND make it more semantic.. see my answer :)

Comment: Yes, it could be done in one line, but realistically this solution would be of interest when there are a *lot* of test strings. Separating the strings from the logic would be (in my opinion) a good idea for code maintenance reasons.  However, if it's a unique situation in the code overall, then you're right of course.

Comment: +1 (I came up with the same idea), but worth noting that if `JSP` happens to contain "toString" or "valueOf" or anything else from `Object.prototype`, you get a false positive.

Comment: Also, you're right about using "in" - definitely looks better. I think I'm still a C programmer at heart.

Comment: You could of course separate them, but the `in` just speaks natural language to the reader of the code :D

Comment: @TJ yes of course that's true.  I suppose you could code it with ".hasOwnProperty()". It's so curious how Stackoverflow makes me think about solving problems that, for some reason, I never actually encounter in my own code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ['test.html', 'test1.html', 'test2.html'];
if (arr.indexOf(JSP)) != -1) {
   alert("found it!");
}
```

relevant docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: Is this really more efficient? Prettier to look at, at least

Comment: This would work, but if the point is performance then it should be noted that this probably won't do any better. The "indexOf" function has no choice but to search the array linearly.

Comment: Depends on what the OP means by "efficient". processing load v.s. lines of code.

Comment: And just a question, how on earth could multiple "OR" statments be too slow?

Comment: great answer! but IE 9 - does not support `indexOf`, work around for hat: https://gist.github.com/1327877

Comment: Well, an object solution (using the strings as property names) is not really significantly more code, and it's **definitely** more efficient in performance terms.

Comment: @Alexandr each string comparison involves looking at the string in "JSP" again.  It's a super-linear solution for that reason: the amount of CPU time is proportional to the length of the search string (JSP) times the average length of the target strings.

Comment: @MarcB - I'm referencing lines of code, because I have 30+ validations, so I don't want to use the full set of "ors" for every validation block

Answer (score 1):

```
if( JSP in {"test.html":0, "test2.html":0, "test3.html":0} ) {
...
}
```

It doesn't get any closer to SQL's `IN( 1, 2, 3)` than this in javascript :-)

Comment: +1 Pretty, but worth noting that if `JSP` happens to contain "toString" or "valueOf" or anything else from `Object.prototype`, you get a false positive. Also, I wouldn't say incurring the overhead of creating the object every time was "efficient." But sure, if the code will only run once, it's certainly easy to read if you know the language.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, that's true but from a pragmatic viewpoint I have to say...seriously? (to the toString and valueOf etc.) :)

Comment: `@Esailija`: I'm just sayin'... ;-) If the OP knows it won't, great, and I've written code making that assumption. I've written other code that had to be more...defensive. "toString" isn't an unreasonable name for the final segment of a web resource. For instance: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString` ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, the OP clearly anticipated that and uses `.html` so you would have `"toString.html"` :D

Comment: `@Esailija`: Yeah...until someone comes along and says: ".html? Really? How...1990s. You really should use clean URLs..." But we're being naughty and chatting in comments. :-) (And I should be working.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (["test.html", "test1.html", "test2.html"].indexOf(JSP) > -1)
```

For browsers that don't support `indexOf` on arrays, [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) suggests short piece of code that adds missing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not more efficient, but you got cleaner ways to do it. You could for instance use a switch-case like this:

```
switch(JSP) {
    case 'test.html':
    case 'test1.html':
    case 'test2.html':
    blablabla; break;
}
```

Or you could create an array out of the urls and see if your string is in the array like this

```
var arr = [
    'test.html', 'test1.html',
    'test2.html'
];
if(arr.indexOf(JSP) != -1) { blablabla; }
```

The last one will not work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing it in jQuery is to use the [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method, e.g.:

```
if ($.inArray(JSP, ["test.html", "test1.html", "test2.html"]) > -1) {
    // your code
}
```

The `inArray` method works in a similar manner to `String.indexOf` so `-1` is returned if no match.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression?

```
if (/^test\d?\.html$/.test(JSP)) { ... }
```

I can't promise that will be more efficient though, just tidier code-wise.

Or if you're already using jQuery, you could use jQuery.inArray():

```
var names = ['test.html', 'test2.html', 'test3.html'];
if ($.inArray(JSP, names)) { ... }
```

Or with [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)

```
var names = ['test.html', 'test2.html', 'test3.html'];
if (_.indexOf(names, JSP) !== -1) { ... }
```